# не работают кнопки replay button в тг боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot

у меня не работают reply button помогите, не понимаю в чем проблема

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start','main','hello']) #реагирование на основные команды
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    bt1 = types.KeyboardButton('что то там')
    markup.add(bt1)
    bt2 = types.KeyboardButton('что то та2')
    bt3 = types.KeyboardButton('что то та3')
    markup.add(bt2,bt3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'как дела?')
```

Comment: чтобы они работали их нужно отправлять, логично? вы же этого не делаете

Answer (score 1):

`reply_markup` отвечает за добавление кнопок

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'как дела?', reply_markup=markup)
```